# Write a function called values, which accepts an object and returns an array of all of the values in the object w/o using Object.values()

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Currently doing practice questions on JavaScript. My code returns an empty array and I'm not sure why:

```js
function values(obj) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i in obj) {
    for (let j in obj[i]) {
      arr.push(obj[i][j]);
    }

  }
  return arr;
}

console.log( values({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }) );
```

Comment: If you are trying to get the values of the object, there is no need for 2 loops. You just need `for (let i in obj) arr.push(obj[i])`. Also, there is a built-in method called [Object.values(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) which returns the values of the object as an array.

Comment: There isn't anything to iterate over in your second loop `for (let j in obj[i])`. I'm not sure what you expect there but there is no real way to iterate over either the key (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`) or the value (`1`, `2`, `3`). It's not clear what you attempt to do with two loops. Ideally you just need `for (let i in obj) { arr.push(obj[i]); }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```js
function values(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  let values = [];
  keys.forEach(key => {
    values.push(obj[key]);
  });
  return values;
}

console.log(values({a: 'b', c: 'd', e: 'f'}));
```

Nobody said you can't use `Object.keys()` ;)